# Set large image as SurfaceView's background so that it suits the display height in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, 2d, surfaceview

I'm using a SurfaceView in Android. The application is always in landscape mode.

In my *res/drawable* folder I have a large background that is also in landscape mode but larger than most display sizes.

[image]

Now I would like to set it as the background of the SurfaceView so that it perfectly fits into the display. So the image's height should be equal to the display's height.

[image]

How do I do that? Do I have to use alternative resources for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi? But even then I don't know the exact height of the display.

I'm currently using:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background), 0, 0, null);
```

I tried to resize the bitmap using a matrix. But then the quality of the image becomes really poor, doesn't it?

(Of course, the solution should be performant, too.)

Comment: "I tried to resize the bitmap using a matrix. But then the quality of the image becomes really poor, doesn't it?" - You tried it, right?

Comment: I did. And the quality became poor. But maybe I did it wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected Bitmap scaled = null;

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    float scale = (float)background.getHeight()/(float)getHeight();
    int newWidth = Math.round(background.getWidth()/scale);
    int newHeight = Math.round(background.getHeight()/scale);
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, newWidth, newHeight, true);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null); // draw the background
}
```